# Ordering a list by first letter matching a set letter

Tags: c#

I have a list of matches that are ordered by a Rank. So an item with a rank of 1 will be higher up the list than an item of 2.

I also always have a variable that the matches should in theory be a close match to, this is what the rank signifies.

Sometimes I have multiple items that all have a ranking of 1, for example.

What I now need to do is continue to order by rank, but then also order by the first letter of the Match, matching the `SpokenWord` variable.

So if I had 3 matches, and a `SpokenWord` variable of "accounts"

```
Name: Dev, Rank: 1

Name: Finance, Rank: 1 

Name: Accounts, Rank: 1
```

I would want Accounts to be moved to the top of the list as it's first letter matches the actual spoken word.

[.Net fiddle of the problem here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vko1RF)

Comment: Why not post the code from fiddle in here? Links to extern pages could become dead in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by `Rank` but then add another sorting, that says if the first letter is equal to the first letter of `spokenWord` mark as 0 otherwise 1.

```
matches.OrderBy(x => x.Rank).ThenBy(x=>x.Name[0] == spokenWord[0] ? 0 : 1)
```

so, in the same rank, all matches with 0 (first letter equal) will be first and then the rest

Answer (score 0):

The other answers give how to order by rank followed by first letter of match, however that would not cover a scenario where in your example the search results had both: accounts and accrual? Then by just matching on first word we may still end up having a wrong sort order.

This points us to the direction where we should try to have another rank based on substring match of the search word to the results. I think this should actually be done in the server side function which is giving you the ranks in the serach result.

However a simple implementation of the same would be:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string spokenWord = "accounts";

    HashSet<string> search = new HashSet<string>(); //tokenize the search keywords and store in dictionary...

    for (int z = 0; z < 1; z++)
    {
        for (int inner = 1; inner <= spokenWord.Length - z; inner++)
        {
            // by default orders in order of increasing length of substring
            search.Add(spokenWord.Substring(z, inner));
        }
    }
    // for loop above wrtten usnig linq....however in this case I think for loops wins becuase of greater clarity
    //var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 1).SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(1, spokenWord.Length - x).Select(j => spokenWord.Substring(x, j)));

    List<Match> matches = new List<Match>();

    matches.Add(new Match { Rank = 1, Name = "dev" });
    matches.Add(new Match { Rank = 1, Name = "finance" });
    matches.Add(new Match { Rank = 1, Name = "accounts" });
    matches.Add(new Match { Rank = 1, Name = "abcounts" });


    // ordering using rank and new searchrank score
    foreach (var match in matches.Select(m => new { Name = m.Name, Rank = m.Rank, SearchRank = MatchRank(search, m.Name) }).OrderBy(x => x.Rank).ThenByDescending(x => x.SearchRank))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Name: {0}, Rank: {1}", match.Name, match.Rank));
    }
}
```

And the `MatchRank` function would be:

```
public static int MatchRank (HashSet<string> searchString, string value)
{
    int result = 0;
    foreach (var item in searchString.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Length))
    {                
        if (value.StartsWith(item, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            result = item.Length;
            break;
        }
        result = 0; // no match
    }
    return result;
}
```

Please do note that this is just a simple implementation, might need to be optimized for performance.